# How to add a product block to the magento 1.9 noItems.phtml page?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, cart, blocks, template

I'm trying to add product blocks to the noitems [your cart is empty] page in magento 1.9 
I kind of figured it would be something like:

```
<checkout_cart_noItems>

     <reference name="content">

          <block>whatever</block>

     </reference>

</checkout_cart_noItems>
```

But it's not, comparing to the default checkout.xml layout file I see that a template is set:

```
<action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
```

How can I add my product blocks to the noItems.phtml file in my local.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `noItems.phtml` template is rendered by the same block as the normal `cart.phtml` template, depending on the number of items in the cart.

But it can contain a child `checkout_cart_empty_widget`, which is only rendered on the `noItems.phtml` cart. It does not exist in the default theme and is an empty container in the default rwd theme (used to attach widgets to it).

If you are using the rwd theme or a theme that is based on the rwd theme, you can add additional blocks to it:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference="checkout.cart.empty.widget">
        <block>whatever</block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

If not, you can add it, the same way as it's done in the rwd theme:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.empty.widget" as="checkout_cart_empty_widget" translate="label">
            <label>Empty Shopping Cart Content Before</label>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

#### Add block below "No items" message:

This block is rendered before the *"You have no items in your shopping cart."* message.

If you want to add something below this message, there is another child, called `shopping.cart.table.after`, which is not created anywhere in the default themes as far as I can see, but it is also rendered in `cart.phtml` of the rwd theme (not the default theme), so if you want to use this and be compatible with different themes, better create a custom product block that is only displayed if the cart is empty:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCount() == 0) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

The layout XML should be like this, to add the referenced but non-existing container block and add yours as a child:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="shopping.cart.table.after" as="shopping.cart.table.after" translate="label">
            <label>Shopping Cart Content After</label>

            <block>whatever</block>

        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: I've been modifying the foundation based theme - luckily it appears to be based on rwd... there was already a definition for the <checkout_cart_index> in my local.  all I had to do was add my block to it.

Comment: good logic.. @fschmengler..  :)

Answer (score 6):

The requirement cannot be achieved by `local.xml` file, *because is no layout handle exist with name `checkout_cart_noItems`* .

For this case,you need to

- create a handler on event `controller_action_layout_load_before`.
- On observer create that handler on when cart qty 0;  name is ***checkout_cart_noItems***.

**Observer code:**

```
    <?php
    class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer
    { 
        /**
         * Before load layout event handler
         *
         * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
         */
        public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
        {

            $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
            if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'cart_index_index') {
                $cart=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')'
                if ($cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount() < 1) {
                    $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
                        ->addHandle('checkout_cart_noItems');
                }
           }
       }
   }
```

**Config.xml code**

```
 <global>
        <models>
            <[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]>
                <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model</class>
            </[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]>
        </models>
    </global>
       <frontend>
            <events>
                <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                    <observers>
                        <my_current_page_is_observer>
                            <class>[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]/observer</class>
                            <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                        </my_current_page_is_observer>
                    </observers>
                </controller_action_layout_load_before>
         </events>
       </frontend>
```

Depends on **this handler** ,you can set **different template**    block

Also you can do anything layout changes .

```
 <checkout_cart_noItems>
     <reference name="content">
         <block>whatever</block>
     </reference>
 <checkout_cart_noItems>
```

Comment: was not able to try this solution as fschmengler's answer happened to work for me.